# Linking Objects from another file doesn't seem to work properly

Tags: linked-data

I'm rather new to blender, so please forgive me if I'm missing something... but here is my problem:

I made a complex hierarchical model for a game. Now I want to link part of it into another .blend file (copying is not an option, because when I continue to edit the linked objects the changes should be applied to the other file too).
When I select a parent object (empty, but is head of a long hierarchy) for linking (using File -> Link), then only the empty object appears without its hierarchy.

I cannot imagine a situation where this would make sense ... but it should definitely not be the default behavior. Of course I want the entire hierarchy to be linked, starting from the object that I select without manually selecting all the sub-objects (which are about 300 right now ...). Moreover, if additional children are added in the hierarchy below the included object, they should appear in the including file too automatically when its reopened ...

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: I'm not experienced with it, but read up on linking libraries in the blender docs. There's a few questions on here regarding it, too, I'm sure.

Comment: Ok, I just found out that I can use groups to do that... this solution seems to work. I still don't understand why linking doesn't link hierarchy, but it really doesn't.